# Create a multidimensional Hash (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails and trying to make a multidimensional hash from different arrays.

```
persons= [person1, person2, person3, person4]
projects= [project1, project2, project3]
issues= [1000, 10001, 1002, 1003, 1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010]
issuetime = [1, 2 , 3, 4, 5]
```

I want a Hash like this:

```
hash = {person 1 =>{project1 => {1000, 1001, 1002 => {1,2,3}}}, person2 =>{project1 => {1003, 1004, 1005 => {3,4,5}}}}
```

I tried:

```
    hash= {}
persons.each_with_index do [person,i]
 if hash.has_key?(person)
  hash[person] << projects[i]
 else
 hash[person] = [projects[i]]
 end
end
```

This is working but it shows me only:

```
hash = {{person 1 =>{project1}}, {person2=>{project2}}}.
```

I want a multidimensional Hash if this is possible. I dont know how to access the next key + value to build a multidimensional hash.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
persons = ['person1', 'person2', 'person3']
projects = ['project1', 'project2', 'project3']
issues = [1000, 10001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009, 1010]
issuetimes = [1, 2 ,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]


persons.each_with_object({}).with_index do |(person, hsh), index|
  hsh[person] = { 
    projects[index] => { 
      issues.slice!(0, 3) => issuetimes.slice!(0, 3) 
    }
  }
end
```

This will give you. `{"person1"=>{"project1"=>{[1000, 10001, 1002]=>[1, 2, 3]}}, "person2"=>{"project2"=>{[1003, 1004, 1005]=>[4, 5, 6]}}, "person3"=>{"project3"=>{[1006, 1007, 1008]=>[7, 8, 9]}}}`

A couple of things to note about this question.

- `{1000, 1001, 1002 => {1,2,3}}` is not a valid hash, as it will throw an error. However, you can do the following `[1, 2, 3]=>[4, 5, 6]}`, so my answer above assumes that is what you want to do.
- My solution uses the destructive form of `slice!`, so note that the `issues` and `issuetimes` arrays will be changed from this solution. If you don't want that I would make duplicates of those arrays using the `dup` method.

On a somewhat related note, you might want to check out [zip](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/zip) when it comes to creating hashes from arrays. `Hash[persons.zip(projects)] // {"person1"=>"project1", "person2"=>"project2", "person3"=>"project3"}`, which is not what you want here, but I thought I would mention it.